# socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, connection

Although I added the following to my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I still get the following error:

```
07-09 13:26:18.650: E/Trace(10542): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-09 13:26:19.830: D/dalvikvm(10542): GC_CONCURRENT freed 44K, 7% free 2774K/2960K, paused 17ms+5ms, total 111ms
07-09 13:26:19.910: W/System.err(10542): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://78.46.124.109 refused
07-09 13:26:19.919: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
07-09 13:26:19.919: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-09 13:26:19.919: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-09 13:26:19.930: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-09 13:26:19.930: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-09 13:26:19.940: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-09 13:26:19.940: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
...
07-09 13:26:19.989: W/System.err(10542): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-09 13:26:20.020: W/System.err(10542):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
07-09 13:26:20.020: W/System.err(10542):    ... 22 more
07-09 13:26:20.020: W/System.err(10542): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-09 13:26:20.040: W/System.err(10542):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:583)
07-09 13:26:20.040: W/System.err(10542):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
```

This is my code in an external file called Logic.java which gets called from the MainActivity.java class:

```
public class Logic {

    public void getJSONFromUrl( String url )
    {
         URL myurl = null;
         String jsoncode = "";

         try {
           myurl = new URL(url);
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
             URLConnection myconn =myurl.openConnection();
             InputStream in= new BufferedInputStream(myconn.getInputStream());
             InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
             String line;
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 sb.append(line);
                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i enter here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             jsoncode = sb.toString();

         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


         System.out.println("json from server:\n" + jsoncode );
        }
}
```

What else could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

After a restart of eclipse adt and the simulator it now works.